# how to use isChecked as a command parameter in that same check boxes command

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So I have a check box that fires a command using WPF/MVVM this works fine but I want to use the IsChecked property of the check box as a command parameter. I tried this.

```
  <CheckBox Margin="3" Content="Clear Selected OEM" 
                              Command="{Binding Path=ClearOemCommand}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

Bu I get an error in the output window that says

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsChecked' property not found on 'object'
```

I would know how to use find ancestor if I wanted to use the property from another control but I am stumped here - it's probably easier than I think... Just not making the connection in my mind.

Thanks!

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked RelativeSource=Self}

Comment: you should make that an answer Arseny so it can be upvoted and searched easier

Comment: http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q5.3.ashx

Comment: RelativeSource=Self - duh... I knew that, I do that so rarely I forgot, THANKS!

Comment: @Arseny: You should post that as an answer...

Comment: @Arseny: You should... ah, you already know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please add *RelativeSource Self* in *CommandParameter*

```
  <CheckBox Margin="3" Content="Clear Selected OEM" 
   Command="{Binding Path=ClearOemCommand}" 
   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the same way the UnChecked state of the CheckBox? If I do the same the compiler says that you can't set CommandParameter more than once.

Comment: @Strum I cannot find Unchecked property in the CheckBox. Even it exists you always can set IsChecked as you want.

Comment: @Arseny hi, can this support `TwoWay` binding? I'd like to bind `IsChecked` property too, something like `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Mode= TwoWay}"`. Or I should bind `IsChecked` separately? I think `CommandParameter` can handle `IsChecked` property (one way), I just doubt that whether I can only use `CommandParameter` to implement `TwoWay` binding `IsChecked` property?

Answer (score 3):

If you run into the following exception, as I did...

Set property `System.Windows.Data.Binding.RelativeSource` threw an exception

Try this instead:

```xaml
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes JW1 is correct. You can use elemen name too like this, that would also work

```
"{Binding Path=IsChecked,ElementName=chkAll}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating command on CheckBox you can bind IsChecked with a CLR property and perform your command logic on setter of CLR property. This is another workaround of handing of command behavior.